# How Can I Make a Book / Book Category?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, design-patterns

TblBook.cs

```cs
public class TBLBook : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TblCategory")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int WriterId { get; set; }
    public string BookYearofPublication { get; set; }//Basım Yılı
    public string BookPublishingHouse { get; set; } //Yayın evi
    public string BookPage { get; set; }
    public bool BookStatus { get; set; }

    public TBLCategory TblCategory { get; set; }
}
```

TblCategory.cs

```
public class TBLCategory : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public  virtual ICollection<TBLBook> TblBooks { get; set; }
}
```

I did this because it is corporate architecture.

```
public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {
        ////return _context.Categories.Include(i => i.SubCategories).ToList();
        public List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter=null)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                return filter == null ? context.Set<TEntity>().ToList() : context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
            }
        }
}
```

Business:

```cs
public List<TBLBook> GetList()
{
    return _bookDal.GetList();
}
```

Controller View

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var query = new BookListViewModel
    {
        TblBooks = _bookService.GetList()
    };
    return View(query);
}
```

Index View:

```
<tr>
    <td>@b.BookId</td>
    <td>@b.BookName</td>
    <td>@b.WriterId</td>
    <td>@b.CategoryId</td>     <!--Problem: @b.TblCategory.CategoryName-->
    <td>@b.BookYearofPublication</td>
    <td>@b.BookPublishingHouse</td>
    <td>@b.BookPage</td>
    <td>@b.BookStatus</td>
</tr>
```

My problem is;
when i do this
@b.TblCategories.CategoryName

throws null or error.

I cannot show the corresponding category name. how can I fill it, thanks.
My English is bad, sorry. I tried to explain with pictures.

In short, here's what I want to do:
The category ID appears. I want it to appear as the Category Name. but it looks blank, what should I fill with.

Screen-shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related entities are not loaded by default.

EF6: [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

EF Core: [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Also don't use a "TBL" prefix in your database or your code, and don't wrap the DbContext in an extra repository layer.  It's already a repository.

So load with a query like:

```
var books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Category).ToList();
```